# Sql Server 2005 cluster - unable to rename to old server name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-cluster

We have a sql 2005 cluster on W2K8 cluster. It is a named instance say SRV1\A. Then I built a new W2K8 (with a diff cluster service name) but the same service account. Then I installed a new sql 2005 cluster say SRV2\A. Now when I bring down the sql server resources on SRV1 and try to rename SRV2\A to SRV1\A through the cluster admin, I get the error the network name already exists. I have tried bringing an old cluster and installing a new cluster with the same name and it works. Why am I not able to rename the name? Any advice would very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Should work in *theory*.  Do you still get the same error if you take the 2005 cluster service totally offline & not just the resource group?

Can you get a screen shot or a copy/paste of the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

Allan Hirt is his book on SQL2005 High Availability advises you can only rename the stuff in DNS - so a named instance such as Crystal\ball, you can only rename Crystal.

On Google Books, look for ISBN 159059780x - and then look at page 334.

So what Allan Hirt is saying is that it is not possible with SQL2005 to rename the instance name - without doing an uninstall and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do the following:

- Bring down network name for old instance
- In DNS, remove the A record for the old instance name
- Wait for DNS replication, check with ping or nslookup
- Rename the network name on the new instance